# get high res images for events in facebook timeline

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i am receiving the timeline of a fb page, including events. 
The given picture for all Entries is usually a low res thumbnail.

I tryed querying for higher res images using the object id like this:

```
 FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/' . $objectId . '?fields=images', []);
```

But i get an error:

```
#100 Tried accessing nonexisting field (images) on node type (Event)
```

Is there any way to get the high-res pictures for events in the timeline? 
Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Event node type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event) don't have an `images` field, but a [Photo node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo) have one.

So you should first get `'/' . $objectId . '?fields=cover'` to get the cover photo node id, and then call `'/' . $coverId . '?fields=images'`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the Solution. I do not understand why FB does this thou. Due to it i have to send more requests to facebook. Let alone the idea to only deliver high-res images per single entry created an immense overhead.

Comment: You may considere [batch your requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests), see the "Specifying dependencies between operations in the request" part of the doc

Comment: Wow. Cool Hint. I'll try that out. Thanks!